# Invoke Nuget From the VS2010 DTE

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio, nuget

I have created an VS Addin that creates a new project conform my specs and file structure.

It does all the heavy lifting as cloning repos from mercurial, adds the needed references to assemblies and projects in the solution.

Now I want to bring it one step beyond.

Is there a way to invoke Nuget from my add-in.
If so then I can install my "standard" packages right after the new solution is created without my personal intervention.

In Nuget there is a reference TO the DTE, but is there a way to use it FROM the DTE.

Answer (score -1):

Use [NuGet.CommandLine](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/NuGet.CommandLine). You can read how to use it [here](http://joseoncode.com/2011/05/31/nuget-keep-your-package-folder-out-of-your-cvs/).

Also make note that NuGet 1.5 brings some [new features](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/marcinon/archive/2011/07/08/project-templates-and-preinstalled-nuget-packages.aspx), though I'm not sure how relevant they are for you.

Comment: The command line was something I figured, it installs the packages but doesn't add the to the project.Nuget 1.5 *seems* to have the features I need.

Comment: You have to add the dependencies to the .csproj file yourself. They don't have to be resolved at creation-time , if you use the PostBuild action I linked.

Comment: Build action is indeed a clever way to do it. I'll stick with it for now. tnx

Comment: NuGet is registered as a MEF extension within Visual Studio so you can definitely access it. What things are you trying to do with it?